# Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is building dependent projects in parallel with what they are dependent on

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a situation where we have six projects in a VS 2008 solution. They have a dependency tree similar to the following:
    A depends on B
    B depends on C, D, E, F
    C depends on F
    D, E, and F have no dependencies.

When I look at the "Build Order" tab in Project dependencies for the solution, everything looks kosher: F, E, D, C, B, A build order.

When I execute the build from the command line (using our continuous integration tool), the build is started in the correct order; however, it is started in parallel.  That is the log shows build items from F, E, D, C intermingled.  Unfortunately, C completes its build before F is complete and thus errors occur.  And, in fact, when fast building projects D & E complete, Visual Studio starts B and A, resulting in even more confusion as dependencies in F and C are incomplete.

How do I force Visual Studio to wait for the completion of dependencies before beginning work on sub-projects?

(Use of Visual Studio 2008 is forced on us for this project due to delivering the project on older CE environment.)

Comment: Short of creating a program to do the build (using CreateProcess and WaitForSingleObject or WaitForMultipleObjects), could you use a make file and/or batch file that did the builds sequentially? The batch file could spawn other batch files for parallel build that uses renaming of files for hand shaking between batch files. To get a 1 second delay for a polling loop, you can use '@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 >nul'.

Comment: I don't want the parallel build.  Frankly the project is small enough that parallel build will not significantly improved the build time. If I could turn off parallel building, it would be fine with me, since then the build would be correct.  Correct trumps fast.

Comment: Any update since then? looks like I've encountered kind of same problem in recent days.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dependency setting in solution level is not suggested, try to use project level dependencey? It works for the similar problem I encountered. Hope it helps.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe/

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586875/msbuild-4-0-incorrectly-processes-project-dependencies-specified-in-solution-file

ps. the referenced articles only apply to VS2010 although...

Answer (score 0):

If parallelism doesn't matter to you, have you tried making that explicit?  From your description, D, E and F can run in parallel.  Can you explicitly make D depend on E and make E depend on F?

I've used multi-project solution in MSVS 2008 and never had a build order problem, but my solution's dependencies dag terminated in 1 project.